# from radiant to degress with numpy.arctan

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

I want to calculate a Gradient with numpy. I use arctan(opposite side/adjacent).
I want a result in degrees. opposite side = 75mm, adjacent = 0.10mm.
adjacent I get as input.

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

Height_B = Decimal(gui.lineEdit_Height2.text())
Height_C = Decimal(gui.lineEdit_Height3.text())

heightdiff =  abs(Height_B - Height_C)

#heightdiff = adjacent, lenght_a = opposite side
x = heightdiff/lenght_a

Gradient_1 = np.arctan(np.rad2deg(x))
```

Comment: You should remove stuff such reading from GUI from your example since it is not relevant to the issue and make sure all needed variables are defined.

Answer (score 2):

When posting an example of your problem, pay attention that it is actually valid code. In your case `lenght_a` is not defined.

Since numpy trigonometric functions work in radians you, first have to calculate the angle in radians and only after that convert to degrees:

```
Gradient_1 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(x))
```